# How to feed an image ROI into session.run() of Tensorflow?

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow

I am trying to feed my image roi into the Tensorflow classifier I took from [here](https://github.com/burliEnterprises/tensorflow-image-classifier/blob/master/classify.py). The idea is to first run a simple filter, get rectangle candidates, and then check (using the network) whether each rectangle(roi) is actually what I am looking for.

```
class ScrewDetector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = None # an internal variable needed for inception network

        # to keep the screw data in
        self.screw_data = dict()

        # load the labels of the classification: screw / non-screw
        self.class_labels = [line.rstrip() for line in tf.gfile.GFile(home + "/imagine_weights/screw_detector/retrained_labels.txt")]

        # prepare the network
        with tf.gfile.FastGFile(home + "/weights/screw_detector/retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()   ##  the graph-graph_def is a saved copy of a TensorFlow graph, object initialization
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read()) # parse serialized protocol buffer data into variable
            _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='') # import a serialized TensorFlow GraphDef protocol buffer, extract objects in the GraphDef as tf.Tensor

        # start the session
        with tf.Session() as self.session:
            self.softmax_tensor = self.session.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')


    def detect_screw(self):

        # get a copy and resize it
        img_raw = self.cv_image.copy()
        resized_img = cv2.resize(img_raw, (0,0), fx=RESIZE_FACTOR, fy=RESIZE_FACTOR)

        # grayscale it
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # detect circles in the image
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 100, param1=50,param2=35,minRadius=15,maxRadius=30)

        # ensure at least some circles were found
        if circles is not None:
            # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
            circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

            # get a counter
            screw_id = 0
            # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
            for (x, y, r) in circles:
                # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle corresponding to the center of the circle
                #cv2.circle(resized_img, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
                cv2.rectangle(resized_img, (x - r, y - r), (x + r, y + r), (0, 0, 255), 5)

                # get the above rectangle as ROI
                screw_roi = resized_img[y:y+r, x:x+r]

                # feed it into the network
                #import IPython; IPython.embed()
                predictions = self.session.run(self.softmax_tensor, feed_dict={screw_id: [screw_roi.flatten()]})

                # get prediction values in array back
                top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

                # output
                for node_id in top_k:
                    human_string = self.class_labels[node_id]
                    score = predictions[0][node_id]
                    print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))

                    # if it is a screw, go on, save its coordinates and append into the network

                    # remap in the original image
                    scaled_point = (round(x * (1/RESIZE_FACTOR)), round(y * (1/RESIZE_FACTOR)))

                    # append to the dict
                    self.screw_data[scaled_point] = r * RESIZE_FACTOR

                    # iterate the counter
                    screw_id += screw_id

            #  publish the result, which is an image (scaled) 
            result_image_msg = Image()
            try:
                result_image_msg = self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(resized_img, "bgr8") 
                #print(self.screw_data)
            except CvBridgeError as e:
                print("Could not make it through the cv bridge of death.")

            self.result_image_pub.publish(result_image_msg)
        else:
            print("No detection of circles.")
```

but I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Can not convert a int into a Tensor.
```

I do know that the variables `screw_id` and `screw_roi` are not empty. And I do know that one needs to feed a dictionary in, which is why in the first place I was trying to do that. But I can't get it running for the reason above.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** So normally, this code loads the image and conducts the prediction as follows:

```
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
```

All I want is to turn this into a form which operates with the image ROI provided during the operation. It can't be too complicated.

Comment: Please make a proper [mcve] to reproduce the problem in the question itself. There is no definition of `screw_id`, `get_candidate` or any other relevant portions of the model for an objective answer (what is `self`?).

Comment: I uploaded most of the code, tried to cut out the irrelevant parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a rocket science, it turns out.

One somehow needs to convert image so that he can pass a string of image bytes, because that's what the function `sess.run()` expects.

If you don't have a file that you want to load from a file system, then the following is the way:

```
image_data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', screw_roi)[1].tostring() # pass a string of image bytes
```

after this, you simply can run:

```
 predictions = self.session.run(self.softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

`feed_dict` expect a dictionary with tensors as keys, to populate the placeholders with the specified valued. It's not in your code snippet how does the `screw_id` is initiated, but I bet it's not a tensor of any kind, hence, your error.

Comment: It's not a tensor, it's just an identifier (int). All I want to do is to run the session on an image of my choice (ROI), rather than loading something from the file system. The answer I expected was how to achieve this.

Comment: And that is the problem, `feed_dict` expects tensor as keys, and it is used to populate those tensors on the session. The key NEEDS to be a `Tensor`, a `placeholder` or a `SparseTensor` and you have to adjust your code to do that if you want specifically to use `feed_dict`. Here's the documentation for further informations:  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/InteractiveSession#run. My suggestion was for you to alter `screw_id` for it to be a tensor and use it with `feed_dict` properly

Comment: I don't necessarily want to use `feed_dict`, I just want to pass an image to the function instead of loading it from the file system..